# Specific command to have a number of dots chosen by the user

Tags: macros, amsmath, expl3, math-operators, xparse

Starting from this simple code,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b\\
\ldots \ldots
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

my question is:

*Isn't there a specific package that creates exactly user-defined suspension dots? Usually it's always three dots and to get six of them, for example, I have to write the specific dot command twice. But if you wanted a default number, 14, 7, which are not multiples of three, what solution would you adopt?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the definition of `\ldots`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%For older distributions
\usepackage{expl3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sebastiano_alotofdots:n #1{
\mathinner{
\prg_replicate:nn{#1}{\ldotp}
}
}
\newcommand{\alotofdots}[1][3]{\sebastiano_alotofdots:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\begin{document}
$\alotofdots$

$\alotofdots[7]$

$\alotofdots[14]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can redefine `\ldots` so it accepts an optional argument, but I wouldn't recommend it.

### EDIT

Thanks to Andrew and Phelype for their suggestions. A more flexible approach, using `xparse` and incorporating the elegant suggestion made by Andrew, could be (colors for highlighting):

```
\documentclass{article}
%For older distributions
\usepackage{expl3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn 
%Thanks, Andrew! This looks way better than my previous example. :) 
\NewDocumentCommand\alotofdots{ D(){\ldotp} O{3}}
{\mathinner{\prg_replicate:nn{#2}{#1}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\begin{document}
    %Three dots (just the same as \ldots)
    $\alotofdots$
    %Number of repetitions is specified by [number]
    $\alotofdots[4]$
    %The dot can be changed by (another symbol)
    %\cdot does not work here
    $\alotofdots(\cdotp)$
    %And now two arguments
    $\alotofdots(\cdotp)[7]$    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I use Papeeria TeXlive 2019 https://www.papeeria.com/ actually but I have several mistakes for the compilation of your code: Undefined control sequence. [\ExplSyntaxOn], Undefined control sequence. [\cs]
/main.tex :3 Missing $ inserted. [\cs_]
/main.tex :3 LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [\cs_]
/main.tex :3 LaTeX Error: Command \_ unavailable in encoding TU. [\cs_new:Npn \a_]
/main.tex :3 You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode. [\cs_new:Npn \a_lot_of_dots #]
/etc. +1 however.

Comment: See my edited answer, please

Comment: +1 You should allow a second optional argument so that, for example, `$\alotofdots(\cdot)[14]$` would use `\cdot` instead of `\ldotp`. Of course, this could allow anything to be put inside but that's ok. This isn't so straightforward with my approach.

Comment: @Andrew Now I'm confused. They're both beautiful all the answers. I don't mark either of them, but I'll make other decisions. 

Comment: @Sebastiano Noone's answer is better as it is easily extendable to other types of dots. They were also first and both solutions are short. It is clear that Noone is more deserving of the tick!

Comment: @Andrew I approve your suggestion .

Comment: @Noone Just a few comment on your answer: `\a_lot_of_dots` is a _really_ bad name for a function. A function in `expl3` should _always_ be named as `\<module>_<name>:<signature>`. Here `<module>` can be `sebastiano` or `manydots`. `<name>` can be `a_lot_of_dots` if you want, or something less wordy that describes what the function does. `<signature>` here must be `n`, because the function takes one argument. (something like `\sebastiano_manydots:n` would be fine).  Also you should use `\cs_new_protected:Npn` here, instead of `\cs_new:Npn`

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to take note of that.

Comment: You can simplify the new version using `\NewDocumentCommand\alotofdots{ D(){\ldotp} O{3} }{\mathinner{\prg_replicate:nn{#2}{#1}}}`. In particular, it is better to use different delimiters for the two optional argument so that they can be used independently.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you to you and **Andrew** for your kindness. My best regards.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you again and, please, see the previous comment :-)

Comment: Do you have put the colors? ..always thank you...you are a nice user. 

Answer (score 8):

Here is another approach using `\dotfill` inside a box of length the number of dots plus 1, all times `1ex`. By default three dots are produced by `\ndots` and an optional argument changes this so that the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ndots[1][3]{%
  \@tempdima=\dimexpr#1ex+1ex\relax%
  \hbox to \@tempdima{\dotfill}%
}
\makeatletter%

\begin{document}

default: \ndots

1: \ndots[1]

2: \ndots[2]

3: \ndots[3]

4: \ndots[4]

5: \ndots[5]

6: \ndots[6]

7: \ndots[7]

8: \ndots[8]

9: \ndots[9]


\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]